# how to do the sum of pixels with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, integral

I have an image and want to find the sum of a part of it and then compared to a threshold.
I have a rectangle drawn on the image and this is the area I need to apply the sum.
I know the cv2.integral function,  but this gives me a matrix as a result. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using **numpy** with index slicing and manipulate with the sum?

Comment: thanks for replying! but might explain me a little more please

Comment: It may be better if you can provide some code, data or the image so your question will be at least in a minimum reproducible form. By the way, welcome to SO!

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum

Answer (score 7):

`np.sum(img[y1:y2, x1:x2, c1:c2])` Where `c1` and `c2` are the channels.

Answer (score 3):

`sumElems` function in OpenCV will help you to find out the sum of the pixels of the whole of the image in python. If you want to find only the sum of a particular portion of an image, you will have to select the ROI of the image on the sum is to be calculated.

As a side note, if you had found out the integral image, the very last pixel represents the sum of all the pixels of the image.

Comment: +1 for mentioning integral images. If tou nedd to calculate sum of more than one part of image using integral images will be much faster than just calculating parts one by one.

Comment: ANy link to sumElems?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum